# Is there a way to redirect a user back to the team site home page after entering an item in a custom list

Tags: custom-list

This is becoming a pretty common occurrence.

We have a custom list that we've created.

Then someone enters an item, and it might contain information that the person doesn't get to edit, so we'd like a way that once a person saves a list item, that it puts them back on the main page of the site.

Answer (score 3):

By default, when users fill out a SharePoint form, they are navigated back to the "All Items" page after pressing OK. You can easily change this behaviour by altering what is in the “source=http://…” part of the URL  "query string" on the form page.

Example: Let's add a link to the Announcements “New Item” form on the home page, so that it returns the user back to the home page after they press ok.

Step 1) Add the following URL to the home page:
http://spsite/Lists/Announcements/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://urlofthehomepage

That’s it! :) Once the user presses OK, the form will read the “source=” part of the URL and navigate the user back to that page.

Reference:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexma/archive/2006/06/17/635346.aspx

Comment: That did the trick Harry.  Is there a way to do it inside the actual NewItem.aspx.  Most of the time I'm going to use your solution, because it's so simple.